# Random quote on click (API + JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I want to show a random quote when a button is clicked. The project is here https://skidle.github.io/projects/random-quote. If you open a console, you can see that this `onclick=newQuote()` function is working because it generates an JSON object into a console. But the quote stays the same, so should I change the URL somehow?

JS:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1");
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === OK) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var elQuote = document.getElementById("quote");
        elQuote.innerHTML = json[0]["content"];
        var elAuthor = document.getElementById("author");
        elAuthor.innerHTML = json[0]["title"];
        console.log(json[0]);
      } else {
        console.log("Error: " + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
      }
    };
  }

var newQuote = function() {
//the script below is the same as above just inserted inside newQuote()
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1");
xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === OK) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var elQuote = document.getElementById("quote");
        elQuote.innerHTML = json[0]["content"];
        var elAuthor = document.getElementById("author");
        elAuthor.innerHTML = json[0]["title"];
        console.log(json[0]);
      } else {
        console.log("Error: " + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
      }
    };
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <section id="quote">
          </section>
          <div class="button-wrapper">
            <button>Tweet this</button>
            <div id="author"></div>
            <button onclick="newQuote()">New quote</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 </main>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the ajax request is beeing cached. Try adding a timestamp to the url, like this:

```
    xhr.open("GET", "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&timestamp="+new Date());
```